# How to use XeLaTeX with TeXstudio in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: latex

I am trying to compile a .tex file in Ubuntu 20.04, and it needs XeLaTeX.

While I can compile it in the command line with `xelatex file.tex`, it is not working in TeXstudio.

```
Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or(fontspec) LuaTeX. \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
Emergency stop. \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
```

How to make TeXstudio use XeLaTeX? I can see XeLaTeX listed in the commands section in TeXstudio settings, but it still does not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open TeXstudio menu, and change the following:

*Options* → *Configure TeXstudio* → *Build* → *Default Compiler* → *XeLaTeX*